# How can i take a message from MQ WEb server and Use it in the body of my API Post request

Tags: jmeter

Question in Regards to the following Scenario:

1. I have a Jmeter script that will authorize user by generating token and using that token to send the request to an api endpoint.. that will process a claim and send back a results.

The Body Request is in XML format.....There are over half a million Record or claims that we have in our dataset which is stored in a database. This record was extracted as messages and placed on an MSMQ ....... I want to have my Jmeter script that would take the message from the queue and use that as the body of the request. How can i do that? or is there a suggestion to do something else?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter provides [JMS Subscriber](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber) which can connect to message queuing systems via [JMS](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/intro-java-message-service.html) and fetch messages from the queue/topic.

In edge cases like IBM MQ you won't be able to use JMS Subscriber, you will need to write some Groovy code in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like it's described in [IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial)

If by MSMQ you mean [Microsoft Message Queuing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) (I don't think this is the case however) you will need to use a 3rd-party library like [this one](https://github.com/jruesga/jmsmq)

Once you get the message from the queue you will be able to store it into a JMeter Variable and use in the subsequent requests.

Comment: MQ Webshere is what i was referring to.